# classification of the groups

Tags: probability, clustering, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

Let's say I have two variables: height and weight. I want to produce 4 groups: high height/high weight, high height/low weight, low height/ high weight and low height/low weight. I also want to see that these four groups are significantly different from one another in terms of hight and weight. Do you suggest me to use cluster analysis (e.g., k-means) or do you know any other simpler method?

Comment: Neither clustering nor testing is appropriate here. This is the task of binning of a scatter plot into 4 cells. And, since this is the action to produce post factum most discriminating groups, significance testing is meaningless.

Comment: What do you think about median splits?

Comment: Yes, median split is one of the way, often being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **predefined goal**, such as your high/low splits, **don't use cluster analysis** at all. Instead, bin your data into your four predefined bins (maybe using quantiles such as the median to define the split)
You can also use more than two bins, e.g. low/normal/high this way easily.

The benefit is that the results will be easy to understand. With cluster analysis, you will likely need to perform another analysis to understand why it clustered the data the way it did.

Cluster-analysis should never be the "end" analysis. It's an interim step to understand your data, but it doesn't really return any further usable result except better *knowledge* of your data. If you run cluster analysis, you next need to analyze the clusters found, and most likely you will need to iterate through this a number of times.