# Help with cluster analysis. Is this possible?

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis, stata

I'm working with the productivity of various government documents. In my data I have two variables (annual frequency and time of resolution) and each document gets its position in a Cartesian plane derived from these two variables (frequency on the vertical axis and time on the horizontal axis).

Now, I define that there are 4 possible groups (or clusters) knowing that the minimum frecuency and time are both 1:

-One group of "Productive and irrelevant" documents with a frequency higher than 1 but lower than the average frequency and a time higher than 1 but lower than the average time.

-One group of "Unproductive and irrelevant" documents with a frequency higher than 1 but lower than the average frequency and a time higher than the average time.

-One group of "Productive and relevant" documents with a frequency higher than the average frequency and a time higher than 1 but lower than the average time.

-And finally a group of "Unproductive and relevant" documents with a frequency higher than the average frequency and a time higher than the average time.

There is I way with the cluster analysis, or with another approach or tool, in Stata, SPSS or R where my clusters can be made? Furthermore, there is a way through I can see what are the minimum changes that an observation must do in its variables to 'migrate' from one cluster to another? Any idea?

Notes: All my variables are discrete. My complete data set is of 1800 observations.

Comment: Are you just asking for code? There is no need for cluster analysis here; you have a set of cut points that you have decided upon a-priori (the variable averages).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use cluster analysis for this.

See also the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/130950/7828

Split your data into quantiles according to your objective (high/low productivity, high/low relevance) and done.

Cluster analysis is *unsupervised*. It does not understand what you are trying to achieve. You seem to have a good understanding of what groups you want to get out - clustering the data with e.g. k-means will likely *not* give you data that is as easy to interpret. There might be near-empty clusters, and they will not be axis-aligned.

Use quantile estimators such as the median (or: **visualization**!) to define your splitting points, split your data, analyze the result. Much easier and more reliable.